# Centering bootstrap responsive columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for the optimal method of centering a group of responsive bootstrap columns inside a row. 
[image: Desired Result]

```
     <li class="row hazRow">
         //center this to the middle of the row
         <div class="col-xs-3">
             <img class="icon" href="#" title="icon" src="img/table/icon.svg">
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
             <p>Title</p>
         </div>
         //end center
     </li>
```

I was thinking of using just blank col either side, but feels like a waste and would not be able to center odd column(s) widths like 7.

I also tried wrapping the columns in a div with class of `.center-block` and `.text-center`, but this did not change the positions.

- Should I abandon responsive bootstrap grids for this?
- How can I center these columns?

Comment: the `.center-block` won't centre the blocks as the grid uses floats which always pulls the columns to the left. I recently had this problem and couldn't find a nice way of fixing it. Only way I sorted mine was with a fixed width :/

Comment: mmmm mite have to try fixed width as a work-around...hopefully someone else might know a way *'cross fingers'*.

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-3">` will put a 3 columns offset at the left of the first one.

Comment: Ah yes, the offset classes, totally forgot about those! Worth using those tbh

Comment: Offsets only work to centre even numbered/totalled columns, column nesting and additional css is required to center odd columns in BS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where we use nested row and col classes...

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4"></div>
           <div class="col-md-8"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

For odd columns: (if you need 9 colums)

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"></div>
           <div class="col-md-6"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This will give you an approx 9 column width.

Comment: Interesting..this only works with even column widths no?

Comment: This is for medium devices (md). You can choose xs or sm, for smaller devices. It all depends upon your needs. Bootstrap provides such a beautiful grid system, if you know how to use it. Yet it saddens me, that even people with few months of experience, mess with it.

Comment: If you know how to experiment, you can make it work for odd columns also. Its just that, u will have to nest few divs. Neways give it a try, experiment, it can work with anything, all you need is an imagination.

Comment: For example, if u want only col-9. So in such case u can have parent col-10 with offset 1 and have child col-12. So parent will gve u the approx required space on both sides, which will look like col-9, approximately.

Comment: Okay i got a down vote, even though my answer works as per his requirements, in optimal way. And it is generic to any column, row, or bootstrap column and row (as you are using bootstrap).

Comment: Revenge-down-voting can get you in trouble with moderators.
All you said to solve the odd columns problem is, and I quote, "If you know how to experiment, you can make it work for odd columns also.". This is not to say your solution will or won't work. You haven't provided the generic solution asked in the question.

Comment: Yeah I see how this works now...I would say this is a good bootstrap orientated solution. Although **cfreear's** answer also displays the same result with the centered class. I'm unsure which to accept.

Comment: What matters is that you understood how to use it, the grid system of bootstrap. Mark any answer that makes you comfortable "smiley face emoticon" ..

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh Your edit is a novel approach and works quite well if you want to go 'pure bootstrap' without adding extra css but the nested nature of calculating the margins means it won't give the same width as a col-xs-9 (or col-xs-7 in OP's case) column.

Comment: @cfreear Yup i agree with you. It wont be exactly col-xs-9 or col-xs-7. But then as you said, without any extra CSS and using pure bootstrap, similar effect can be achieved. Anyway, i liked your answer, that idea never came into my mind. +1 already from me.

Comment: @Orbitall while both answers give you the solution you desire, AjitKumarSingh's came first so if you are having difficult deciding between the two, you should accept his.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by borrowing slightly from [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#centered-columns)

As others have suggested the first step is to nest your columns in an 'outer' column:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 centered">
        <div class="row hazRow">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                icon.svg
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Notice the outer column has your desired width of 7 and the inners now add up to 12)

Then add css to stop the outer column from floating and center it:

```
.centered {
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/f2uuqab5/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
         <img class="icon" href="#" title="icon" src="img/table/icon.svg">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
         <p>Title</p>
     </div>
```

Comment: The question does not want you to define what internal columns to use. The solution should be generic to any columns added inside the row.